# A version of Hahn-Banach separation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a closed convex set and let $L$ be a line not intersecting $X$. Is there a hyperplane containing L and not intersecting $X$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is a separation theorem stating that two convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the relative interior of one of them does not intersect the other can be separated by a hyperplane (this is in J. van Tiel's book on Convex Analysis, for example). The theorem applies to your set and your line. Such hyperplane has to be parallel to the line of course. Now just shift your hyperplane parallel to itself until it contains the line. The separation is not necessarily strict unless your convex set is compact.

Comment: Do you mean Theorems 3.8 and 3.9 in the book? According to these theorems, $X$ and $L$ can be separated properly which means both of them can not be contained in a hyperplane but that does not mean that this hyperplane does not intersects $X$.

Comment: If a hyperplane does not intersect a line then the generator $v$ (direction vector) of the line has to belong to the vector subspace $S$ associated with the hyperplane. You can then append to $v$ $n-2$ l. i. Vectors to generate $S$. In other words you can shift the hyperplane in the direction perpendicular to itself and the line until it contains the line. Since you are moving it towards the line your convex set will be at all times on one side of it. I can check the numbers of the theorems later.

Comment: If the hyperplane does intersect the line, the line has to be contained in it. Otherwise it would be transversal having points on the same open half-space as the convex set, contradicting separation.